# webpage not loading javascript script

Tags: javascript

so, I have this webpage here [ http://saikonet.org ] and it's not loading the tipsy script. If you go into the source, it's on line 11. Now, the strange part is all the other scripts are loading fine, and if you click on the tipsy script link, it's loads fine in browser, so syntax and filepath are both fine. even stranger is that is was working completely fine last time I checked.. it just stopped working all the sudden. I'm not sure how to proceed..

(and btw, the way I checked whether it's loading or not was via the script tab in chromium's 'inspect element')

Comment: BTW. Line 14 is absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tipsy script is being loaded before the jquery file where the former is dependent on the latter.

Change:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the jQuery file before you load the tipsy JS file.

In your head section, change this:

`<script src="/js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"`>`</script`>
   `<script src="/js/jquery.tipsy.js"`>`</script`>

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"`>`</script`>

To This:

`<script src="/js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"`>`</script`>
   `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"`>`</script`> 
  `<script src="/js/jquery.tipsy.js"`>`</script`>

Answer (score 0):

On my Chrome it looks like the tipsy script `jquery.tipsy.js` *is* being downloaded.

At any rate, I think you may need to put your tipsy script *after* your jQuery script.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
```